# Issue with TP4054/How not to damage li-po charger ICs

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, circuit-protection

My issue is: The TP4054 I am using started drawing 150 mA after something I did. I know that I have probably fried it and the obvious answer is I should ditch it and take a new one. However I am not sure what exactly caused the failure and I would like to know it for the future, and also so I don't fry the remaining ICs I have. Here goes the story:

I have designed a board in which I am using a li-po battery. Naturally I want to be able to charge it so I decided to use a [TP4054](https://lcsc.com/product-detail/PMIC-Battery-Management_TP4054_C32574.html), which is carried by my chosen assembly house. An English language datasheet is [here](http://images.100y.com.tw/pdf_file/38-TP-TP4054x.pdf). Here is the configuration I am using: [image]
A 5.5x2.1 DC connector goes into a TP4054, which charges a battery connected to the J3 "JST_PH" connector (disregard the J2 "POWER" component, it is for connection redundancy), which then goes into a 3.3 V regulator to supply the circuit. I've used 10K resistor to set the max charging current to 100mA. 
I will now explain my steps during the assembly and testing of the board.

When I initially assembled the board and wanted to test it, I first plugged in the DC jack. My power supply was a 5 volt adjustable supply with insignificant ripple. The circuit powered up, being supplied by the voltage from TP4054. I quickly disconnected the DC jack since the circuit started to turn on and off, I guess due to the fact that TP4054 regulates voltage by switching. Then I connected the battery and tested if the battery was actually being charged. And it was, since the battery voltage rose from 3.95 to 4.05 in half an hour or so, that I had the charger connected. After a while I decided to check the power draw in my circuit. With the charger disconnected I measured the current from the battery and got about 150mA. I checked the PCB for the hot spots using a wet finger technique and sure enough the TP4054 was at fault. After I removed the IC the circuit drew a more usual 5mA or so.

The question is: what could have gone wrong? I couldn't have exceeded the voltage rating for the IC, since the maximum it was connected to was 5V. Can a static shock cause such damage in those ICs? Maybe it's a common issue and I should avoid using those ICs alltogether? What's the general "safe" approach to using li-po charger ICs so that a chance for such issues is minimized?

Edit: Made clear that the high current was being drawn from the battery, not the charger.

Comment: no, the datasheet says its a voltage regulator, not a switcher: "constant current/constant voltage **linear** charger", so that on-and-off switching was not intended

Comment: How is your TP4054 supposed to know how much current is going into the battery and how much is going into J3 and/or U2?

Comment: Lol, that datasheet is using figures literally stolen from the linear/Analog devices [LTC4054](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/405442xf.pdf) datasheet. Maybe simply read that instead, and buy the original. I wouldn't believe any claim on sustainable charging currents, reliability under capacitive load etc from that TP4054 datasheet, seeing that it's a clone of someone who doesn't even care to draw their own test circuit schematics...

Comment: and honestly, you're even spending more on that rip-off 4054 than you would have spent on a similar [100 mA-capable linear charger](https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/MCP73811T-420I-OT/MCP73811T-420I-OTCT-ND/1649474) from a reputable source (e.g. mouser, digikey). Why do you do this (LCSC) to yourself? I want you to be well...

Comment: @MarcusMüller Oh a simple reason! One well-known PCB manufacturing/assembly house carries those for dirt-cheap, and also has everything else for similarly low prices. Just following my human nature (cheapness of it plus I'm lazy to solder those fine-pitch parts) into the trap of Chinese electronics industry. I'll try to replace those if I find a replacement in my area, which I doubt.

Comment: I know for a fact that mouser ships to China, arrow and digikey do, too. So simply don't order components from your  board house, but get them shipped there by reputable distributors. That's a usual service mode!

Comment: @Finbarr No way it's gonna know that comes to my mind. Then again that;s the configuration given in most datasheets I've managed to find.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yup, I'll know from now on. But hey, it's an experience I'm not likely to forget! Thanks for the advice!

Comment: _"the battery voltage rose from 3.95 to 4.05 in half an hour or so"_ - what capacity is the battery?

Comment: @BruceAbbott 500mAh. Take the time value with a chunk of salt I didn't measure anything.

Comment: Guesstimate time is ok. At 100mA a 500mAh cell should receive ~10% charge in 1/2 hr. Going from 3.95V to 4.05V equates to ~10% charge put in, which suggests the TP4054 was working at that time. Perhaps you just had a bad chip (the TP4054 runs hot in normal operation, so a 'weak' chip could could fail quickly). Time to try another one! Note that output will not be stable if the battery is not connected.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Well, that explains the erratic behavior in the beginning. I won't power it up without the battery connected and will see how it goes. Thanks for the input!